# Oracle how to remove a 0 from every number

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to remove a 0 from all my ids within the table.

I first run a procedure with them existing but after the procedure need to remove them. Please can someone show me how?

Thanks

*Edit:*

Sorry so for eg.

```
100020
100030
100040
```

I need to remove the 0's at the end.

Comment: could you give a couple "before and after" examples. I can't tell if you're trying to remove the character `0` or rows with an id of `0`.

Comment: Where in the number is the 0?  Can you just divide by 10?  Cast the number to a string then use substring functions?

Answer (score 3):

`REGEXP_REPLACE` is one way to do it if the `id` is a character type.

```
UPDATE my_table
SET id = REGEXP_REPLACE(id, '0$')
```

If it's a numeric type, just divide by 10 but *only if the ID is a multiple of 10*:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET id = id / 10
WHERE MOD(id, 10) = 0
```